# How do I upload a PDF file to Parse server?

Tags: java, android, server, uri, parse-server

I need help uploading pdf file to the parse server using JAVA in android Studio.

I tried using the following code:

```
private ParseObject uploadPDFToParse(File PDFFile, ParseObject po, String columnName){

    if(PDFFile != null){
        Log.d("EB", "PDFFile is not NULL: " + PDFFile.toString());
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BufferedInputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(PDFFile));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int read;
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        try {
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0)
            {
                out.write(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] pdfBytes = out.toByteArray();

        // Create the ParseFile
        ParseFile file = new ParseFile(PDFFile.getName() , pdfBytes);
        po.put(columnName, file);

        // Upload the file into Parse Cloud
        file.saveInBackground();
        po.saveInBackground();
    }
    return po;
}
```

I get this error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.jackady.notebytebylev3l, PID: 31048
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   dat=content://com.mi.android.globalFileexplorer.myprovider/external_files/Download/CourseRegistrationReport
>   (1).pdf flg=0x1 }} to activity
>   {com.jackady.notebytebylev3l/com.jackady.notebytebylev3l.uploadPDF}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(byte[])' on a null object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4419)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4461)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(byte[])' on a
>   null object reference
>           at com.jackady.notebytebylev3l.uploadPDF.uploadPDFToParse(uploadPDF.java:43)
>           at com.jackady.notebytebylev3l.uploadPDF.onActivityResult(uploadPDF.java:140)
>           at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7590)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4412)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4461) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)

Comment: What is the class of your `PDFFile` object?

Comment: PDFFile is of File type that i declared using the path obtained from uri.getpath()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code and let me know:

```java
private ParseObject uploadPDFToParse(File PDFFile, ParseObject po, String columnName){

    if(PDFFile != null){
        Log.d("EB", "PDFFile is not NULL: " + PDFFile.toString());
        int size = (int) file.length();
        byte[] pdfBytes = new byte[size];

        try {
            BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            buf.read(pdfBytes, 0, pdfBytes.length);
            buf.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Create the ParseFile
        ParseFile file = new ParseFile(PDFFile.getName() , pdfBytes);
        po.put(columnName, file);

        // Upload the file into Parse Cloud
        file.save();
        po.saveInBackground();
    }
    return po;
}
```